# Getting an error when everything's supposed to work

Tags: flutter, oop, dart

I'm building an app with Flutter where you can add files to the app's cache.

There are 2 things that are not working, which I don't understand why.

Here's the [source](https://pastebin.com/cmUFqMKT)

1. Whenever I launch the app for the first time (with absolutely no cache) I get this error

> Directory listing failed, path = '/data/user/0/com.example.lockedapp/cache/file_picker/' (OS Error:
> No such file or directory, errno = 2)

Even though I made precautions to create the directory before trying to display it.

```
  bool checkFilesEmpty() {
    
    var cache = new Directory('/data/user/0/com.example.lockedapp/cache/file_picker');
  
    cache.exists().then((resp) => { if (!resp) { cache.create() } }); // creates a new cache directory if it does not exist

    return cache.listSync(recursive: false).toList().length != 0; // returns false if it's empty
}
```

on line 31, the `checkFilesEmpty` is checked first and then comes everything else, but i still get the error.

the weird thing is that if I relaunch the app, it works as it's intended.

Any solutions for this? I'm really confused

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put your **checkFilesEmpty** in initState method of Stateful widget hence it will be called on before your widget is building.

```
class MyHomeState extends State<MyHome> {
  bool filesEmpty;
    @override
    void initState() {
        super.initState();
        filesEmpty = checkFilesEmpty();
    }
.
. // Your rest of code
.
}
```

You can put your error causing statement in try catch block. If there is no listing then you can create one in catch block:

```
  bool checkFilesEmpty() { 
    try{
      var cache = new Directory('/data/user/0/com.example.lockedapp/cache/file_picker');
      return cache.listSync(recursive: false).toList().length != 0; 
    }
    catch{
        cache = Directory('/data/user/0/com.example.lockedapp/cache/file_picker').create() ;
        return cache.listSync(recursive: false).toList().length != 0; 
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello, your solution is kinda what I was been looking for, but It still does not work.

Comment: Just try new try catch block I have added to same solution

Comment: Error does not happen here.

Comment: it happens when It's trying to display the ```List<FileSystemEntity> files``` variable